# How to get term from alias

Tags: path-aliases

I've to get the `taxonomy_term` tid from the alias ('`/alias/of/my/term`')

Is there a way to do this without making a query on url_alias table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to avoid a query is if the alias is already in the cache. Rather than worry about that yourself, it's best to use the API (even more so in Drupal 8 as path alias storage is pluggable and may not be in the database):

- Drupal 7, using [`drupal_get_normal_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_normal_path/7.x) :

  ```
  $system_path = drupal_get_normal_path($path_alias, $langcode);
  ```
- Drupal 8, using the [path alias manager service](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/path.alias_manager/8.3.x):

  ```
  $system_path = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getPathByAlias($path_alias, $langcode);
  ```

  As always it's preferable to inject the service into the consuming class if context allows.

Both methods will get you the system path, e.g. taxonomy/term/1, from which you can extract the term ID.